# Loading Json file in jquery fails in the following code

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I got a huge problem!

I'm trying to load a Json file with Jquery but it always fails! 
I've tried many different things, but nothing worked for me .  I am also not sure how to really debug it, what is wrong!

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
    var url = "content.json";
    var outp = {
                    low         :   0,
                    high        :   99,
                    name        :   "Fritz",
                    rufnummer   :   "012",
                    faxnummer   :   "345",
                    mobil       :   "678",
                    mail        :   "mail@mail.mail",  
                };

    $('#find').on("click", function(){

        var data = $.getJSON( url, function() {
          console.log( "success" );
        })
          .done(function() {
            console.log( "second success" );
          })
          .fail(function() {
            console.log( "error" );
          })
          .always(function() {
            console.log( "complete" );
          });

            console.log(data);      
            console.log(outp);
            console.log("Hi");

           data.complete(function() {
             console.log( "second complete" );
           });
        });
    });
//});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Postleitszahl:</p>
    <input type="number" autocomplete="on" name="inp" id="inp">
    <button type="button" id="find">Finden</button>
    <p class="output"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Also here is my JSON:

```
{
    "low"         :   0,
    "high"        :   99,
    "name"        :   "Fritz",
    "rufnummer"   :   "012",
    "faxnummer"   :   "345",
    "mobil"       :   "678",
    "mail"        :   "mail@mail.mail",  
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of:

```
var data = $.getJSON( url, function() {...})
```

Try with:

```
$.getJSON( url, function(data) {...})
```

Comment: Thanks for the Help, but I tried that already! If i do that, it wont even make it to the console.log's! Also on the reference I used : [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) the jqXHR Object is explained, wich I'm trying to accieve.

Comment: @NiklasFett of course it won't because they run before the *asynchronous* operation has completed!

Comment: @freedomn-m : No, if the OP try this `(console.log("result"))` he will get string "result" :)

Comment: @freedomn-m but wouldn't the console.log's show at least anything? To show my Json right after the Operation solved my Problem somehow! Also I have my jqXHR Object now! :) This is my working solution:
`var data = $.getJSON( url, function() {console.log(data);});`

Comment: Make it: $.getJSON( url, function(result) { console.log(result); }) and you'll see your json.

Comment: @NiklasFett given that your variable is ambiguously called "data", it should be safe to assume you want the ... data... to be loaded into it, *not* the jqXHR which is not "data".

Comment: You're right! I want the data! I was only magically surprised that i got some result! And the `$.getJSON( url, function(result) { console.log(result); })` works fine, i just didnt realize because the program executes the bottom console.log before it uses the getJson line. I dont know why! Is there any special rule with jquery about some line execution?

Comment: Yes. $.getJSON is async so its been excecuted at the same time as the other lines. You have to wait for the request to finish before manipulate result

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like the answer from `Roxoradev` or try this:

```
data.complete(function() {
   console.log( data );
});
```

instead of

```
data.complete(function() {
   console.log( "second complete" );
});
```

**Explain**

Your deferred is now stored in `data` if you want do solve it call it with `.complete(func)` or `.done(func)`

**From Docs:**

> The Promise interface in jQuery 1.5 also allows jQuery's Ajax methods, including $.getJSON(), to chain multiple .done(), .always(), and .fail() callbacks on a single request, and even to assign these callbacks after the request may have completed. If the request is already complete, the callback is fired immediately.

So you can also write `.done()`